# Azure Deployment Entity Framework Connection String Keyword not supported: 'metadata'

Tags: entity-framework, azure, deployment, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service

I have been developing an application locally using asp and entity framework to interact with my database. I am using a model first approach.  I want to deploy this app to Azure but I keep getting the error "Keyword not supported: 'metadata'."

Through searching and reading posts like this: [Windows Azure, Entity Framework. Keyword not supported: 'metadata'.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13908348/windows-azure-entity-framework-keyword-not-supported-metadata)

I know its an issue with my connection strings but i can't figure out what i'm doing wrong.

Connection string in my local web config:

```
<add name="BeCivicData" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.BeCivicData.csdl|res://*/Models.BeCivicData.ssdl|res://*/Models.BeCivicData.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.;initial catalog=BeCivic;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /></connectionStrings>
```

Generated Connection String for the Azure DB:

```
Server=tcp:becivicserver.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=BeCivic;Persist Security Info=False;User ID={MyID};Password={MyPass}5;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;
```

On the Azure Applications settings page i have defined my connection string as both of the above which didnt work so i tried combining them to have the EF meta data (below) but the Azure connection string and that also gave me the Meta Data error:

```
metadata=res://*/Models.BeCivicData.csdl|res://*/Models.BeCivicData.ssdl|res://*/Models.BeCivicData.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string="Server=tcp:becivicserver.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=BeCivic;Persist Security Info=False;User ID={myid};Password={mypass}5;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;" " providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"
```

In my application the EF .edmx file is in a folder named Models.

Both the database element and the code elements deployed separately to azure successfully and now i just need to link them up.

Answer (score 1):

> Keyword Not Supported:metadata

When you attempt to use the the connectionstring within the Azure Portal `Connection Strings` setting, it will get the above error.

So, try to change the type from `SQLAzure` to `Custom`.
[image]

You could refer to this [article](https://www.blacksandsolutions.co/blog/posts/database-first-connection-strings-on-azure/) to troubleshoot.

To avoid parsing the connection string yourself, you can use the `EntityConnectionStringBuilder` class the parse the string and retrieve the database connection string from its [ProviderConnectionString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/how-to-build-an-entityconnection-connection-string) property.

Comment: I realized what i was doing wrong. I have two connection strings one of them is Entity Framework, one is not, but i was giving them the same connection string which caused the issue on the non-EF data connection.