# How to user Azure Key Vault with an Entity Framework connection string

Tags: c#, .net, azure, entity-framework, azure-keyvault

I am trying to encrypt my app service's connection string via Azure Key Vault and this [guide](https://intelequia.com/blog/post/2070/storing-azure-app-service-secrets-on-azure-key-vault) and I am getting the following error:
`The specified named connection is either not found in the configuration, not intended to be used with the EntityClient provider, or not valid.` I originally thought it was because of the " characters in the string so I replaced those with actual "'s. Now I'm thinking it may be because it is not a normal connection string, but a db first entity framework one as shown:
`connectionString="metadata=&quot;res://*/Models.{Project}.csdl|res://*/Models.{Project}.ssdl|res://*/Models.{Project}.msl&quot;;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source={datasource};initial catalog={db};persist security info=True;user id={id};password={password};MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />`

(bracketed values are there just to hide the sensitive info). How do I get this to work w/ Azure Key Vault?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. the ONLY quotes in the connection string have to be from after provider connection string= and at the end and most importantly they need to be SINGLE QUOTES i.e '.

Comment: Thank you. This saved my ass. There was just additional problem that even though I did server restart right after adding the new version of the model connnection string secret to keyvault, it did not update right away.

I had done logging of the connection string without credentials, which showed that the double quotes were still there, so I did refer to the specific secret version in the keyvault reference and it started working.

My error page:
> Keyword not supported: 'data source'.

And fix: `;provider connection string='Data Source=` to have single quote instead of `&quot;` or `"`.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below ways that may solve the issue.

1 . The configuration file might  have `&quot;` instead of `"`, .The web sites in azure must change &quote value to `“` from connection string.Also check if it is properly configured in portal.

(or)

2 . Along with try 1 ,select "Custom"  type of connection string instead of "SQL server" or "SQL azure"( as shown in provided link) for the Entity Framework  while configuring connection string in app service.

Comment: Neither of these worked. In my post above I mention I already removed the "&quot;"'s and 2. did give me a new error: `keyword '"metadata' not supported`

Comment: Please check with starting and ending " in the connection string and compare to the one in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13908348/windows-azure-entity-framework-keyword-not-supported-metadata/13916625#13916625) and check if you may have to add local db connection in web.config file like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13782337/retrieve-and-use-windows-azures-connection-strings/37938912#37938912). Please see that there must be quotes separately for and from  'provider connection string i.e; till app=entity framework' .

Comment: this is it now and I'm getting keyword "initial catalog" not supported. `metadata=res://*/Models.Project.csdl|res://*/Models.Project.ssdl|res://*/Models.Project.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient; provider connection string=”Data Source=tcp:server,1433; Initial Catalog=dbname;integrated security=False; persist security info=True;user id=id@servername; password=************;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework”`